# Developer story bug - 'save as pdf' messes up email

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

When saving my developer story as pdf via the "save as pdf" button on the right sight, the email in the resulting .pdf file is messed up.

In my case, `@gmail.com` gets displayed as `@gamil.com`.

I double-checked my own settings for this typo, however all seems to be correct.

Comment: This is, ummm, weird. We don't play with any of the data before it makes its way into the PDF. Investigating!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sigh*, we have a lot of email addresses kicking around the database for a user. There's an on-going project to eliminate all this crazy, a large amount of which was introduced as part of integrating Careers into SO as /jobs.

In short, the PDF export functionality uses the email address from your job preferences, because usually when you want a PDF of your story it'll be for a job.

Yours currently has a typo in it; you can fix it by editing your [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current). In the 'Jobs Emails' section you'll find the differing email address.

[image: Jobs Emails]

Comment: I don't have a field in that section, does it only appear when you have different email addresses?

Comment: @Stijn yes, that's right.